# Как вывести название родительской таксономии на странице дочерней к ней ? WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть одна родительская таксономия, и три дочерних.
Как вывести на страницах дочерних название родительской таксономии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если только название - тогда как-то так:

```
echo get_term_by('id',get_queried_object()->parent,get_queried_object()->taxonomy)->name ;
```

Детальнее про get_term_by https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_term_by; 
get_queried_object https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_queried_object

Comment: Спасибо большое )